# what do `^^^` and `~>` mean in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm read the [sbt documentation on Commands](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Commands.html), and wondering what do `^^^` and `~>` mean?

I tried to google but nothing found, these chars are escaped by google I guess...Thanks a lot

```
  // Demonstration of a custom parser.
  // The command changes the foreground or background terminal color
  //  according to the input.
  lazy val change = Space ~> (reset | setColor)
  lazy val reset = token("reset" ^^^ "\033[0m")
  lazy val color = token( Space ~> ("blue" ^^^ "4" | "green" ^^^ "2") )
  lazy val select = token( "fg" ^^^ "3" | "bg" ^^^ "4" )
  lazy val setColor = (select ~ color) map { case (g, c) => "\033[" + g + c + "m" }

  def changeColor = Command("color")(_ => change) { (state, ansicode) =>
    print(ansicode)
    state
  }
```

The full code is as example `project/CommandExample.scala` at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Commands.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are methods on the RichParser class.

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/#sbt.complete.RichParser

Hint. If you look for symbolic methods click the '#' on the upper left corner of the api doc page.

- `^^^[B](value: B): Parser[B]`: Apply the original Parser, but provide value as the result if it succeeds.
- `~>[B](b: Parser[B]): Parser[B]`: Produces a Parser that applies the original Parser and then applies next (in order), discarding the result of the original parser.